# ValidationError [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] only in special cases

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When editing a model field through Django Admin, I'm getting a `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` validation error.

Steps:

- Edit a model through Django Admin and insert a special character
  (é,ñ)
- The data is saved OK.
- When editing again the model field
  (charField) the validation error is raised, whatever the input is.

When editing without special characters, the form is working ok.

**Edit**

When saving a special character, the inlines for that model doesn't show up in the edit section, so the validation error is correct in that case.

Relevant code:

```
class StreamInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Stream
    form = StreamForm
    extra = 0
    #define order
    fields = ('name', 'canal', 'tipo', 'stream_type',
              'unit', 'formula', 'label', 'color',
              ('min_scale', 'max_scale', 'fixed_scale'), 'enabled')
    readonly_fields = ['name', 'stream_type']
    can_delete = False

    class Media:
        js = ('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'js/jscolor.min.js',)


class NodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name', ]

    fields = (('identifier', 'name', 'node_type'), ('group','cultivation') , ('longitude', 'latitude','operator','sim_card','telephone'), 'config', ('enabled', 'deleted'),('date_node','date_bat','reference_irrig_date'),'notes')
    list_display = ['identifier', 'name', 'group', 'sim_card']
    list_filter = ('group__name',)

    #form = NodeForm

    #list_filter = ['deleted', 'enabled', 'node_type']
    inlines = [StreamInline]
```

Django Version: 1.4.21

Python Version: 2.7.9

Answer (score 1):

The error: `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` was because the inlines doesn't appear, so the MAX_TOTAL_FORMS and others doesn't concord.

The inlines didn't appear because there were errors in `__unicode__` functions from the models.

Returning unicode type (python 2) in the `__unicode__` function solved the issue.